# Update using joins by finding the previous value in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I have to update the address field in the emp table by looking up in the emphistory table with previous value i.e USA for employee John

Table emp

```
EId ename sal Address AccountId 
-------------------------------
101 John  100   U        X12
102 Peter 500   Null     X13
```

Table emphistory

```
emphisid  EId AccountId Address  Date (use row_number to find the second record for that eid and accountid)
-----------------------------------------------------
1         101  X12      U        11-01-2020 09:45:00
2         102  X13      Null     11-01-2020 09:46:00
3.        101  X12      USA      11-01-2020 09:30:00
```

I have to join the tables with account id and eid.

Comment: Please tag the type of database or RDBMS you're using. When it comes to syntax like for the UPDATE statement then there are often differences between them.

Comment: What is the "previous value" supposed to mean? For John there are two rows, You want the older one. What if there are more? Do you want the second newest or the oldest one? And what about Peter? There is only one row. Do you want it because it is the oldest one or ignore it because you want the second newest? If you want the oldest row: The value is null, so give Peter the value null? And if you want the second newest one: There is none, so leave the value as is or make it null?

Comment: Thanks Kettner for your response.I edited the data.I always want the second newest value based on date.For John the second newest value is USA so the address in the emp table has to be updated with USA and for Peter it doesn’t have any second newest value so the value will be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Postgresql & Sql Server

```
UPDATE emp
SET Address = hist.Address
FROM (
  SELECT h.EId, h.AccountId, h.Address
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.EId, h.AccountId 
                       ORDER BY h.Date DESC) AS Rn
  FROM emphistory h
  JOIN emp e
    ON e.EId = h.EId
   AND e.AccountId = h.AccountId
  WHERE h.Address IS NOT NULL
) hist
WHERE emp.EId = hist.EId
  AND hist.Rn = 2
```

Comment: Hi LukStorms thanks for your reply.I didnot understand why you are looking for adress is null or not.Their values can be null.I want the second newest value for that empid and accountid and update it with that value.

Comment: Also if we use Rn 1 then it will display the first record and I want the second newest record for that empid and accountid.

Comment: @learner123 Ok, so you really want the second newest. I've changed the order in the row_number and now getting rn = 2. And removed the IS NULL criteria.